# Getting Latest Does Not Work When I Change From Desktop To Laptop

Tags: tfs

When I check-in at my desktop (or laptop) and later changes computer to opposite one and requests a get latest then TFS won't update any files just checked in. The only way I've found to fix this is either to delete the local project or executing a get specific version that says to 'overwrite all files even if the local version matches the specified version'.

I'm thinking this is either because I'm using the same TFS account on both computers. Can this really be true? Working on multiple machines as the same user must be a common scenario.

What approach should I take to fix or avoid this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of the duplicate login.  I had the same issue.  There was also a bug back in the day (don't remember which version) where Get Latest didn't actually recurse through the directories correctly.  I just got specific version every single time.  It wasn't that much harder (4 clicks vs. 2) so I've just gotten used to getting specific every single time.

Comment: My favorite TFS bug is/was that you can't have a computer name with a lower case letter if you want to get latest.  Not sure if it's still an issue, but TFS refused to acknowledge my computer name until I removed the lower case letter.  Oddly enough, I had a lower case letter in my comp name to test a defect in code that I was writing :)

Comment: I've a hard time acknowledging that MS has decided to implement it this way. This must be a very common scenario with people working both on a desktop and laptop. Or home- and work station. Thanks for the specification tho :)